# Server is not responding on multiple requests through API

Tags: php, api, server, request

I created API for my android application and when I made multiple requests from my android application server is not responding for a while even the website is can't be reached.

**This happens when I made another request before the first request is completed. I create a simple PHP API.**

Thanks in advance.

My API Code:

```
switch ($_POST['method']) {

case 'say_hello':

  $data="Hello There..Welcome";
  echo json_encode($data);

break;

case 'breakfast':

  $data="Hello There..Breakfast is ready";
  echo json_encode($data);

break;

default:

      $msg     = "Please Select any category This is default!";
      $mainArr = array(
      'status' => "0",
      'msg' => $msg,

      );
      echo json_encode($mainArr);
      exit();

break;
```

}

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code?

Comment: and maybe server related logs (as your first call may trouble your app)

Comment: @nagyl thanks for responding ..please check.

Comment: Hi @boly38, I checked this. I tried by changing the order of requests the same thing happens

Comment: PHP looks OK, but it isn't well written. Indent the break;-s. I think your application will be the problem. Can you paste the code that calls this API? Also as @boly38 mentioned, your logs might help as well!

Comment: @nagyl API is working fine in postman with multiple requests but when I make multiple requests from the application server stops working for a while. I think the problem is in my application's code.

Comment: Then post that code too.